# execute a function after redirecting - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, i have a simple button on my page (MyPage) which fades out the current div (fade 1) and fade in another one (fade 2). I have now realised that there might be chances that i would want to go to that page (fade 2) from somewhere else directly. I am able to redirect my page by `window.location`. However i also want that if that link was pressed (from some other random page), go to page (fade 1) and then `fadeOut`the current div and `fadeIn` another one (fade 2).

Hope this isn't too confusing. This is the code i am using to get to the page (MyPage):

```
$('#fav').click(function(){
    window.location = 'production/produc_order.php';
    $('#view_production').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#create_order').fadeIn('slow');
})
```

Comment: once you use `window.location` the browser loads the new page ... nothing after it will be executed. investigate AJAX use if you want to just load in a part of a page

Comment: You want it to send the user to page B, but still execute code from page A even after sending the user to page B?

Comment: The user is redirect to page A using `window.location` but what i want is that after redirect it should basically perform the function of that button (i.e fade out current div and fade in another one).

Comment: @ManseUK could you please elaborate on the investigating AJAX bit. Do you mean that i should stay on the same page and load whatever i want there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the `window.location` will kill all scripts currently running in the browser.

Your only other solution is getting a page via `AJAX` and run a callback function to execute when the content is loaded. [Here is something to get you started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Also, [jQuery as a nice `.ajax()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to easily perform `AJAX` requests and associate callbacks to successful and failed requests.

Comment: Exactly, so how can i perform the other operations that i want.

Comment: the first link in your answer is no longer maintained, could you please update your answer @RémiBreton

Comment: how to run a script (for example show modal) after redirect?

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to or can't re-code your page to support AJAX, the other old-school option is to pass a parameter in the URL as a hint to the refreshed page. (You can hide it by making the redirect a POST if you feel it's really necessary, or use a cookie technique. The point is that the refreshed page needs a token of some form from the prior page.)

eg:

```
$('#fav').click(function(){
    window.location = 'production/produc_order.php?create=1';
})
```

and put the fade code inside the `$(document).ready()` function, with a check for the `create` parameter, cookie or whatever.

I'll agree with @remibreton though, using AJAX is the more hip, modern method.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with sessionStorage()

```
$('#fav').click(function(){
  sessionStorage.setItem("reloading", "true");
  window.location = 'production/produc_order.php';
});
var reloading = sessionStorage.getItem("reloading");
if(reloading == true) {
  sessionStorage.removeItem("reloading");
  $('#view_production').fadeOut('slow');
  $('#create_order').fadeIn('slow');
}
```