# jQuery - change attribute of a page after being redirected to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

So I'm making a wordpress site, and as such, I want to keep my custom javascript to a minimum.
Basically, I have Page1 and Page2, each with several child pages. In the Page1-children, there are links to the Page2-children. The Page2-children have a "Back" button in them that currently just navigate to Page2. What I'm trying to accomplish is: if the Page2-child was navigated to from a Page1-child, I'd like to set the href of the "Back" button to the page it was navigated from. Here's what I've got so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.application-button').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var currURL = window.location;
        window.location.href = event.currentTarget.href;
        $('.dynamic-link').attr('href', currURL); //<-- .dynamic-link is a class of the Back button
        //I figured that if it came after the window.location change, it would still be called

    });

});
```

I'm sorry if the explanation before the code is hard to follow, but I can't really explain it in too much more detail, as it is somewhat work-sensitive.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not do this in PHP and just use `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` as the adress for the back link?

Comment: Hm. I'll look into that. Again, I want to keep this as simple as possible, and I'm not familiar with adding custom PHP to wordpress themes. Oh well, should be a learning experience I suppose! I'll reply and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to navigate to the last page in javascript

```
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back()
}
</script>

<body>
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
</body>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

In your case :

```
$('.application-button').on('click', function(event){window.history.back();});
```

Comment: I've thought of that, and it is likely the simplest option. 

My only remaining concern with this solution is that if the user navigates directly to this page without going through the usual pages (just by typing it in the address bar, for example), then clicking the button could mean that the use goes back to some completely unrelated site. So it would make the button seem to not be doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: A good option for you then would be the use of a cookie or session. You could set a cookie "returnURL" that would be activated if the referer is on of the pages... The cookie is a good option in a sense that it can be used via the server and the client (javascript)

Comment: Yeah, I'll try that. My initial idea was flawed, as, pointed out in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524606/execute-a-function-after-redirecting-javascript), "Changing the window.location will kill all scripts currently running in the browser."