# Function not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

```
function displayjob1(ref,position)
{
  document.getElementById("jobref").value=ref;
  document.getElementById("jobp").value=position; 
}

function store()
{
  var jobref1=100011;
  var jobposition1="Application Engineer"; 
  displayjob1(jobref1,jobposition1);
}

function link()
{
  window.location.href='enquire.html';
  store();
}

function job() {
  click1=document.getElementById("job1");
  click1.onclick=link;
}

window.onload=job;
```

when the page is loaded and I clicked a button link, it goes to `enquire.html`, but then the `store()` and `display()` won't work as the textbox has no value after another page is loaded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [execute a function after redirecting - javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524606/execute-a-function-after-redirecting-javascript)

Comment: With every page load, the html refreshes. You can store variables in cookies if you want them to "survive" page reload

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the textbox has no value, the problem is the textbox and the javascript code do not exist anymore! You have to send any data you need as a parameter in the URL, and then obtain it from another piece of code in the new page.

UPDATE: As you point at, you can use the local storage, but then again: store anything you need before changing the location, and have code in the new page to fetch that data when "onload"

Comment: What I wanted to do is use JavaScript to store jobref and jobposition in local storage when the link is clicked. Then, jobref and jobposition is retrieved from local storage when enquiry page is loaded

Comment: how to code new page onload in javascript instead of code in html <body onload>?

Comment: What I meant is that you have to create a new page with its own JS code that fetches that information. It has to be totally independent from this first page.